# AJAX POST request accepts number but not String

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Alright, I have looked around for this problem, but I can only find references to JSON, which I am currently not using. The array value that has a number in it passes, and the DIV updates. However, when ever I try to pass in a string, nothing happens. Here is the code:

```
<php> 
$cont = array();
$cont[] = 'yo';
$cont[] = '2';
foreach($cont as $c){
  $statement .= '<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"nFunc('.$c.')\">'.$c.'</button>';
}
</php>
<script>

function nFunc(str)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("p="+str);
}
</script>
<div id="myDiv">Default</div>
{$statement}
```

Please note I am doing testing with AJAX via IP.Board/IP.Content, so the  tags and variables in {} are parsed by the IP.C engine.

This code outputs two buttons labeled "yo" and "2". When "2" is clicked, the DIV updates correctly. When "yo" is clicked, nothing occurs.

The test.php file is very simple:

```
<?php
$hello = $_POST['p'];
echo $hello;
?>
```

Thanks for any help beforehand.

Comment: instead of `echo` use `var_dump`. It will give detailed information about variable.

Comment: <php>Which version of html you are using ?</php>

Comment: @PLB 'var_dump' did not help, and it is also giving me the location of the data, which I do not want.

Comment: @DinoBabu This is HTML5, but IP.B processes the <php> tags

Comment: @DeathDream You need to debug your code so you need more information about what's passed to find issue faster.

Comment: @PLB I have tried some debugging, and I also tried passing a raw String into the nFunc instead of a variable, and it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This output `HTML` from your `PHP` Statement is invalid:

```
<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"nFunc(yo)\">yo</button><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"nFunc(2)\">2</button>
```

Notice  `onclick=\"nFunc(yo)\">`

See your string parameter is not enclosed in quotes and also those backslashes are not needed there. That is why you see that error, which of course doesn't happen in case of a number.

```
$statement .= '<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"nFunc('.$c.')\">'.$c.'</button>';
```

should be

```
$statement .= '<button type="button" onclick="nFunc(\''.$c.'\')">'.$c.'</button>';
```

It works like a charm after that fix,  I just tested.

Comment: I thought about this, and tried it out, but I'm getting a compiler error through IP.B

**IP.Board Message
The contents that you submitted would create a parser error when compiled into appropriate PHP code. Please verify any PHP code, template tags and template plugin tags (such as parse blocks) and resubmit your data.**

Comment: Sorry i have no idea about `B IP, Board Message` or its format. But the issue as far as PHP and HTML syntax is concerned was whats mentioned above